# How to know which custom controller handle a certain CRD

Tags: kubernetes

With `CRD` we can extend the functionality of kubernetes, but how could I know which `controller` handle a certain CRD, I mean I know there is a CRD registered in my kubernetes named `foo` but how could I know which `controller/pod` do the reconcile for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of knowing just by looking at the CRDs. Several different controllers could be watching the same CRD, it's not like there is a 1-1 relationship.

If you really need to know, there would be ways of figuring this out, like enabling the audit log and inspecting the calls received by the k8s api.